# Can't get bash regular expression work

Tags: regex, bash

This is part of my script:

```
   if [[ `hostname --fqdn` != '(\S+-laptop)' ]]; then
            echo "Wrong node, run it on server"
            exit 1
    fi

    echo "testing ok"
    exit 0
```

this is result:

```
++ hostname --fqdn
+ [[ mylinux1-laptop != \(\\\S\+\-\l\a\p\t\o\p\) ]]
+ echo 'Wrong node, run it on server'
Wrong node, run it on server
+ exit 1
```

I tested it on online tools and worked - can't figure why not in shell...

Thanks for help.

Comment: `!=` is a string comparison, not a regex match.

Comment: why don't you use *-laptop instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct BASH regex syntax is:

```
[[ ! "$(hostname --fqdn)" =~ [^[:space:]]+-laptop ]] && echo "Wrong node!" && exit 1
```

- regex in BASH don't require quotes around them
- `\S` doesn't work on BASH regex engine
- Use `[^[:space:]]` to match anything but whitespace
- BASH regex operator is `=~`
- Negation should be at the start of the condition

You can also use **shell glob** instead of regex:

```
[[ "$(hostname --fqdn)" != [^\ ]*"-laptop" ]]
```